# PHP MySQL query fail error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to sum from a query but I get error, here is the code

```
FROM `sales` WHERE `invoice` = .$show[invoice].");
```

The error I get is

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

I know the error is in .$show[invoice]. but it is the first time I create a complicated query like this a query from a query and that is why I do not know how to write the correct code. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the whole query and take a look at your escaping too. You  miss a **"** after invoice =

Comment: And vardump $show[invoice]

Answer (score -1):

Show more of your code, but the problem probably lies in your omitted quotation mark. Try this:

```
FROM `sales` WHERE `invoice` = ".$show[invoice].");
```

Comment: same error, the problem is in the quotation mark but is not working

Comment: Can't believe I get downvoted for trying to help :( Impossible to help further without more lines of your code..